# Invitation API in Linkedin is not working properly? Can somebody share me the code?

Tags: iphone

Here is the XML file   i am using to send invitaion by email-id ---
       NSString * requestString= @"\
       \
       \
   \
       \
       ABC\
       XYZ\
       \
   \
       \
       Invitation to Connect\
       Please join my professional network on LinkedIn.\
       \
   \
       friend\
   \
       \
       ";
Here is the XML file using to send invitaion by member-id ---
       NSString * requestString= @"\
       \
       \
   \
       \
   \
       \
       Invitation to Connect\
       Please join my professional network on LinkedIn.\
       \
   \
       friend\
       \
       NAME_SEARCH\
       y6Xn\
       \
   \
       \
       ";
But i am getting the error- 

401
1309502595763
5L213R30ZX
0
[unauthorized]. OAU:LaWgkYHS6ZfSdW8dzeBY5N2mzZTeVzxe5nNKXrfyEDGkYE8lvP00LYZAotqjRg4z|21e7b7a4-23da-4f64-b698-5049de5f8ff8|*01|*01:1309502595:3fEir09U8VFqpZgpLhySEon9dvE=

Can any one know why i am getting the error?
Please Help me out.....

Answer (score 0):

No body will write a whole code for you.So you have to tell what you have done so far & where you are facing problem.

For reference you can refer to [this post.](http://developer.linkedin.com/message/9738#9738)

Also if you have any doubt using Linkedin API then you can ask your question in [LinkedIn API discussion forum.](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis?view=discussions)